# Adding regression line to vega-lite scatterplot

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I'm trying to add a simple regression line to my vega-lite plot but I'm unsure [where to integrate this code](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/regression/) any ideas?

```
let spec = {
      "data": { "values": iris },
      "mark": "point",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Sepal_Length","type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "Sepal_Width","type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }

vegaEmbed("#vis", spec, {})
```

I've included all the code within this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MayaGans/qdj20Lws/ any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vega-Lite does not have any built-in capability to compute regression lines. But if you have the regression lines pre-computed, you can use a layered chart to put them on the same axis. For example:

```
{
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {"url": "data/iris.json"},
      "mark": "point",
      "transform": [
        {"filter": "datum.species == 'setosa'"}
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "sepalWidth"},
        "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "sepalLength"}
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"x": 0, "y": 2},
          {"x": 5, "y": 6.5}
        ]
      },
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "x"},
        "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "y"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Do you have a preferred package/function to compute the lm values?

Comment: Note that the upcoming Vega-Lite v4 will have regression support.  See https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/4976/commits/b4765a670fa2765b8d2d40dc9db9f788ca4e82df.   Stay tuned for the release!